# for loop running infinitely

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, programming, array, shift-register

```
void writereg() {
  digitalWrite(latchPin, LOW);
  for (int i = 7; i >= 0; i--) {
    digitalWrite(clockPin, LOW);
    Serial.print("wswitch&&&&&&");
    Serial.print(i);
    Serial.print("----------------------");
    digitalWrite(dataPin, switches[i].stat);
    Serial.println(switches[i].stat);
    digitalWrite(clockPin, HIGH);
  }
  digitalWrite(latchPin, HIGH);
  touched = false;
}
```

I don't understand what's wrong with what I'm doing here, but this for loop runs into an almost infinite loop and prints crazily. I'm a newbie to electronics and Arduino and I don't understand what's wrong here. Please help.

This is my switch class:

```
struct Swtch
{
  int num;
  bool stat;
  bool touched;
};

Swtch switches[8] = {{1, 0, 0}, {2, 0, 0}, {3, 0, 0}, {4, 0, 0}, {5, 0, 0}, {6, 0, 0}, {7, 0, 0}, {8, 0, 0}};
```

[image]

Comment: From the output, it looks like `i` is not an `int` but a `byte` (or `unsigned char`  or `uint8_t`). In this case, what you observe is normal because an `unsigned` is *always positive*, hence the loop never ends. Are you sure the output posted here matches the code in your question?

Comment: Yes. Its the same code that produces this output. i is an int only and not a byte.

Comment: Could you show how `switches` was declared (and details of the underlying type)?

Comment: i have edited the question. Please see and let me know if it can solve the issue im facing.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately, that did not show any potential issue of memory overwriting (which is what I thought of when I asked you to add this code). Sorry to insist, but I am really surprised that `i` is an `int`. Just in case, do you have special compilation options?

Comment: As a test, could you replace your loop with `for (int i = 0; i <= 7; i++)` and inside the loop body, replace `i` everywhere with `7 - i` ? That would not explain the behavior you get, but that should fix your problem.

Comment: Im not sure about this. I was not facing this issue when I was working with Arduino Uno. I have compiled this code to a Atmega328p now and this causes the issue. The code was working properly in Uno.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71035/discussion-between-bukke-hari-prasad-and-jfpoilpret).

Answer (score 8):

After a chat with OP, it turned out this was a more complex issue, probably a memory overrun.

This cannot be seen in this small snippet, but the whole program is using memory extensively (global variables and dynamic memory heap allocation).

Heavy use of `String` variables is a likely explanation for the observed behavior.
Also a lot of string literals are putting more pressure on memory in the OP program.

Here are my suggestions:

1. Replace all `"..."` string literals with flash-stored strings with `F("...")`. That will reduce the initial SRAM size used.
2. Replace all `String` variables with pure C-string (`char*` and char arrays) and use standard C string functions such as `strcpy`, `strcat`, `strlen`, `strcmp`, `strchr`... This forces to pre-allocate string to their maximum size, but this can be controlled at compile-time (for string variables defined as global). For this point, I also suggest to read a good tutorial on strings in C language.
3. Use `const` whenever possible (instead of variables that waste memory)
4. Use the smallest type needed for each variable, e.g. avoid `int` (2 bytes) when you need to store a boolean value, prefer `bool` type (only one byte) or even use 1 byte to store 8 boolean values and use boolean logic to manipulate each value.

Comment: Thanks and i would make all the changes that you suggested. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Like [jfpoilpret](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/48311/for-loop-running-infinitely#comment96255_48311) said, it looks like `i` is being treated as an `unsigned char` or `uint8_t` causing it to never go below zero. Instead it wraps around to 255, the max value of an 8-bit unsigned integer, as you can see in line 9 of your output. The condition to remain in the loop is `i >= 0` which means the loop will never exit. A solution is to add a case for if `i` is above the starting value:

`for (int i = 7; i >= 0 && i <= 7; i--) {`

I would recommend finding out why `int` is being treated as `uint8_t` for any future projects

Comment: I tried this too. But it didnt work.

Answer (score -1):

I have noticed that you have incorrectly declared the switches array.

Your code:

```
struct Swtch
{
  int num;
  bool stat;
  bool touched;
};

Swtch switches[8] = {{1, 0, 0}, {2, 0, 0}, {3, 0, 0}, {4, 0, 0}, {5, 0, 0}, {6, 0, 0}, {7, 0, 0}, {8, 0, 0}};
```

It should be:

```
struct Swtch
{
  int num;
  bool stat;
  bool touched;
};

struct Swtch switches[8] = {{1, 0, 0}, {2, 0, 0}, {3, 0, 0}, {4, 0, 0}, {5, 0, 0}, {6, 0, 0}, {7, 0, 0}, {8, 0, 0}};
```

Alternatively, you could make a typedef struct:

```
typedef struct
{
  int num;
  bool stat;
  bool touched;
}Swtch;

Swtch switches[8] = {{1, 0, 0}, {2, 0, 0}, {3, 0, 0}, {4, 0, 0}, {5, 0, 0}, {6, 0, 0}, {7, 0, 0}, {8, 0, 0}};
```

References:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32185804/6075112
https://overiq.com/c-programming/101/array-of-structures-in-c/#initializing-array-of-structures
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3275389/6075112

Comment: This would be true for C,  not for C++, and I do not know in what language the code in the question is.

Comment: The Arduino development tools by default use C++.

Comment: Isn't the typedef the best practice?

Comment: @sa_leinad: No. In C++, it's generally considered quite ugly, as there's no good reason for it. (C++ lets you treat user-defined type names like built-in type names in nearly all cases.)

Comment: Thanks all for your comments. I have learnt something today!